# "Attempt to dereference a null object" when getting value from Map

Tags: apex, map

I need to pull the ID for a custom object record, BCS__c, using the User__c as the lookup. I keep getting the error "attempt to dereference a null object" in `The_Hub__c = hubMap.get(cs.l11_sc__User__c).Id`. I am still trying to figure out how to use maps.

```
List<l11_sc__Composite_Score__c> cScores = new list<l11_sc__Composite_Score__c>([
            SELECT Id,l11_sc__Composite_Score__c,l11_sc__Date__c,l11_sc__Scorecard_Config__c,l11_sc__User__c 
            FROM l11_sc__Composite_Score__c
            WHERE l11_sc__Date__c = Yesterday LIMIT 1
        ]);

        Map<Id, BCS__c> hubMap = new Map<Id, BCS__c>([Select Id,User__c FROM BCS__c]);

        //Create list for update
        List<Hub_Scorecard__c> scorecards = new list<Hub_Scorecard__c>();

        for (l11_sc__Composite_Score__c cs:cscores){
            system.debug('user = '+ cs.l11_sc__User__c);
            //Debug shows the 18 char ID for user

            scorecards.add(new Hub_Scorecard__c(
                The_Hub__c              = hubMap.get(cs.l11_sc__User__c).Id,
                Scorecard_Date__c       = cs.l11_sc__Date__c,
                LPI_Profile__c          = cs.l11_sc__Scorecard_Config__c,
                LPI_Composite_Score__c  = cs.l11_sc__Composite_Score__c
            ));
        }

        system.debug('scorecards' + scorecards);
```

Comment: Problem line is:The_Hub__c              = hubMap.get(cs.l11_sc__User__c).Id,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You issue is the Map Key is the ID of the `BCS__c` record and you are attempting to use the `User__c` value to get the record.

Two important points:

1. Always check map keys before blindly dereferencing to a value

e.g. `if(hubMap.conainsKey(...somevalue...){ /*do action*/ }`

2. Ensure the key are of the same type and from the same object

to do what you want creat a map using the `User__c` as a key:

```
Map<Id, BCS__c> hubMap = new Map<Id, BCS__c>();

for(BCS__c b : [Select Id,User__c FROM BCS__c]){
   hubMap.put(b.User__c,b);
}
```

now you can do this:

```
List<Hub_Scorecard__c> scorecards = new list<Hub_Scorecard__c>();

        for (l11_sc__Composite_Score__c cs:cscores){

            system.debug('user = '+ cs.l11_sc__User__c);
            //Debug shows the 18 char ID for user

            Hub_Scorecard__c tmp = new Hub_Scorecard__c(
                Scorecard_Date__c       = cs.l11_sc__Date__c,
                LPI_Profile__c          = cs.l11_sc__Scorecard_Config__c,
                LPI_Composite_Score__c  = cs.l11_sc__Composite_Score__c
            );

            if(hubMap.containsKey(cs.l1l_sc__User__c)){
              tmp.The_Hub__c = hubMap.get(cs.l11_sc__User__c).Id;
              scorecards.add(tmp);
            }
        }
```

your login on creating the new record and adding it to the list may vary but hopefully this gives you a start